# Hazelcast listeners don't work after client reconnects

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

My hazelcast client got disconnected because of possible memory outbreak. After the client reconnects, it is not getting getting messages from listeners on maps and topics. Is there a way to make the client active to the listeners again ?

This is how I am initiating a listener in my client/service:

```
IMap liveMap = hazelcastCacheClientService.getMap("MYMAP");
MyListener myMapListener = new MyListener();
liveMap.addEntryListener(myMapListener,true);
```

This is how my listener looks like:

```
public class MyListener implements EntryListener {

    @Override
    public void entryAdded(EntryEvent entryEvent) {
         //do something
    }

    @Override
    public void entryEvicted(EntryEvent entryEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void entryRemoved(EntryEvent entryEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void entryUpdated(EntryEvent entryEvent) {
        //do something
    }

    @Override
    public void mapCleared(MapEvent mapEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mapEvicted(MapEvent mapEvent) {

    }
}
```

I have multiple other services, who put entries into the map.

Comment: can show ur code here?

Comment: @m.nguyencntt updated with code.

Answer (score 0):

If your version is 3.9 or older it could be a bug. We improved the client reconnect logic in 3.10 and further improved it in 3.11. Here are the 3.11 documentation for client reconnect configuration: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#configuring-client-connection-retry

Now having said that I always recommend an additional circuit breaker pattern such as the one from netflix: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works

In order to restore the client listeners it is best to destroy the hazelcastinstance and create a new one. This forces all the sockets to perform an init during startup. Hazelcast is a socket application so if you suffer from 1/2 open sockets then there is not much Hazelcast can do about restoring the connections.

Hope this helps,